# QWidget - resize animation

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qwidget

Say I have a `QHBoxLayout` where there are 2 `QTextEdit`s and between them a button with an arrow to the right. When you click on the button, the right-side `QTextEdit` gradually closes by moving the left border until it meets the right one. Simultaneously, the right border of the left `QTextEdit` takes the place which the right `QTextEdit` released. And after pressing on the button, the state of the system is coming to the former one.

EDIT: In order to organize this I have done the following:

1) In header file:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT

    QTextEdit       *m_textEditor1;
    QTextEdit       *m_textEditor2;
    QPushButton     *m_pushButton;
    QHBoxLayout     *m_layout;
    int              m_deltaX;

public:

    MyWidget(QWidget * parent = 0);


    ~MyWidget(){}


private slots:
    void closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool isClosing);


};
```

2) In the source file:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget * parent):QWidget(parent),m_deltaX(0)
{


  m_pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
  m_pushButton->setText(">");
  m_pushButton->setCheckable(true);
  connect(m_pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool)));

  m_textEditor1 = new QTextEdit(this);
  m_textEditor1->setText("AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA  AA");

  m_textEditor2 = new QTextEdit(this);


  m_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  m_layout->addWidget(m_textEditor1);
  m_layout->addWidget(m_pushButton);
  m_layout->addWidget(m_textEditor2);

  setLayout(m_layout);
}

void MyWidget::closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool isClosing)
{
    QPropertyAnimation *animation1 = new QPropertyAnimation(m_textEditor2, "geometry");
    QPropertyAnimation *animation2 = new QPropertyAnimation(m_pushButton, "geometry");
    QPropertyAnimation *animation3 = new QPropertyAnimation(m_textEditor1, "geometry");

    if(isClosing) //close the second textEdit
    {
        m_pushButton->setText("<");

        QRect te2_1 = m_textEditor2->geometry();
        m_deltaX = te2_1.width()-3;
        QRect te2_2(te2_1.x()+m_deltaX, te2_1.y(), 3 ,te2_1.height());

        QRect pb_1 = m_pushButton->geometry();
        QRect pb_2(pb_1.x()+m_deltaX, pb_1.y(), pb_1.width() ,pb_1.height());

        QRect te1_1 = m_textEditor1->geometry();
        QRect te1_2(te1_1.x(), te1_1.y(), te1_1.width()+m_deltaX, te1_1.height());


         //animation->setDuration(10000);
         animation1->setStartValue(te2_1);
         animation1->setEndValue(te2_2);

         animation2->setStartValue(pb_1);
         animation2->setEndValue(pb_2);

         animation3->setStartValue(te1_1);
         animation3->setEndValue(te1_2);
    }
    else //open
    {
       m_pushButton->setText(">");

       QRect te2_1 = m_textEditor2->geometry();
       QRect te2_2(te2_1.x()-m_deltaX, te2_1.y(), 3+m_deltaX ,te2_1.height());

       QRect pb_1 = m_pushButton->geometry();
       QRect pb_2(pb_1.x()-m_deltaX, pb_1.y(), pb_1.width() ,pb_1.height());

       QRect te1_1 = m_textEditor1->geometry();
       QRect te1_2(te1_1.x(), te1_1.y(), te1_1.width()-m_deltaX, te1_1.height());


        //animation->setDuration(10000);
        animation1->setStartValue(te2_1);
        animation1->setEndValue(te2_2);

        animation2->setStartValue(pb_1);
        animation2->setEndValue(pb_2);

        animation3->setStartValue(te1_1);
        animation3->setEndValue(te1_2);

    }
    animation1->start();
    animation2->start();
    animation3->start();
}
```

EDIT:

And I have the following problem:

When I close the second `QTextEdit` (by clicking on the button) and resize the `MyWidget`, then the `QTextEdit` restores its state (but it should stay closed of course). How can I solve this problem?

Please provide me with a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what I wanted:

**Header file**

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT

    QTextEdit       *m_textEditor1;
    QTextEdit       *m_textEditor2;
    QPushButton     *m_pushButton;
    QHBoxLayout     *m_layout;
    QVBoxLayout     *m_buttonLayout;

    int              m_deltaX;
    bool             m_isClosed;


public:

    MyWidget(QWidget * parent = 0);
    ~MyWidget(){}

    void resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * event );

private slots:
    void closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool isClosing);

};
```

**Source file**

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget * parent):QWidget(parent),m_deltaX(0)
{

  m_pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
  m_pushButton->setText(">");
  m_pushButton->setCheckable(true);
  m_pushButton->setFixedSize(16,16);
  connect(m_pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool)));

  m_textEditor1 = new QTextEdit(this);
  m_textEditor1->setText("AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA  AA");

  m_textEditor2 = new QTextEdit(this);

  m_buttonLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
  m_buttonLayout->addWidget(m_pushButton);
  m_buttonLayout->addItem( new QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding) );


  m_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  m_layout->addWidget(m_textEditor1, 10);
  m_layout->addSpacing(15);
  m_layout->addLayout(m_buttonLayout);
  m_layout->setSpacing(0);
  m_layout->addWidget(m_textEditor2, 4);

  setLayout(m_layout);
  resize(800,500);
}

void MyWidget::closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool isClosing)
{
    m_isClosed = isClosing;
    QPropertyAnimation *animation1 = new QPropertyAnimation(m_textEditor2, "maximumWidth");

    if(isClosing) //close the second textEdit
    {
        m_textEditor2->setMaximumWidth(m_textEditor2->width());

        int textEdit2_start = m_textEditor2->maximumWidth();

        m_deltaX = textEdit2_start;
        int textEdit2_end = 3;



        animation1->setDuration(500);
        animation1->setStartValue(textEdit2_start);
        animation1->setEndValue(textEdit2_end);


        m_pushButton->setText("<");

    }
    else //open
    {


        int textEdit2_start = m_textEditor2->maximumWidth();
        int textEdit2_end = m_deltaX;


        animation1->setDuration(500);
        animation1->setStartValue(textEdit2_start);
        animation1->setEndValue(textEdit2_end);


        m_pushButton->setText(">");

    }

    animation1->start();

}


void MyWidget::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * event )
{
    if(!m_isClosed)
        m_textEditor2->setMaximumWidth( QWIDGETSIZE_MAX );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a description of your solution, as opposed to highly specific to your situation code, would be more helpful to other people on SO

Answer (score 3):

[Qt's Animation framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/animation-overview.html) sounds like a good place to start.  You could just try to follow their tutorials, adapting for you use case.  I have used it already, and it seemed quite straight forward.

Comment: I have read and got acquainted with the examples. Unfortunately my experience does not let me implement the situation.

Comment: @Narek Why?  Can you elaborate?  What was the problem?

Comment: Ok I have changed my question. Please see above.

Answer (score 3):

1) You could replace your button with a vertical layout, place the button inside this layout and finally add a vertical spacer below the button (in same the layout).

```
...

QVBoxLayout* m_buttonLayout = new QVBoxLayout();

m_layout = new QHBoxLayout();
m_layout->addWidget(m_textEditor1);
m_layout->addLayout(m_buttonLayout);
m_layout->addWidget(m_textEditor2);

m_buttonLayout->addWidget(m_pushButton);
m_buttonLayout->addItem( new QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding) );
```

2) I guess you could (and should) animate widget's maximumSize (or just maximumWidth) property and let the layout take care of calculating actual geometries. This would also simplify your calculations. E.g.

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation1 = new QPropertyAnimation(m_textEditor2, "maximumWidth");
QPropertyAnimation *animation2 = new QPropertyAnimation(m_textEditor, "maximumWidth");

if (isClosing)
{
    int textEdit2_start = m_textEditor2->maximumWidth();
    int textEdit2_end = 0;

    int textEdit_start = m_textEditor->maximumWidth();
    int textEdit_end = textEdit_start + textEdit2_start;

    animation1->setStartValue(textEdit2_start);
    ...
}
```

Also, now you don't have to animate buttons geometry at all (assuming that you have set fixed size to it).

PS. I didn't compile codes so there might be minor errors but you should get the idea.

Comment: How can I remove the distance between the button and the right QTextEdit(it originally exists in QHBoxLayout)?

Comment: Your logic for solution of the second problem is fine, but the is a little problem: it waits a little then closes the second QTextEdit immediately. When I added animation1->setDuration(3000);, it waited more and then, the same behavior, imediatley closed. How can we make to do it gradually?

Comment: You can use QBoxLayout::setStretchFactor to get rid of that gap between elements in layout (i.e., set stretch factors to zero for each widget). For the other problem, you could try to animate minimumWidth also.

Comment: minimumWidth works, but maxmimuWidth no. Thus I have opend a bug on http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/.

Comment: You could see the bug here: http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1916

Comment: Animating maximumWidth worked just fine for me (tested on both Linux and N900) so I guess it is related only to Windows environment

Comment: Did you use my code? I have placed it here: http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-12332. May I ask you to take a look to new.h and new.cpp files, please? It actally works but  it does it immediately, there is no animation. That is the problem.