# Why it is not possible to animate the "maximumWidth" parameter of the QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qwidget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Qt - There is a bug in QPropertyAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326690/qt-there-is-a-bug-in-qpropertyanimation)

I wanted to animate the QWidget maximumWidth in order to change thd widgets size in a layout with animation, but it does not work. I have tried to do the following:

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation1 = new QPropertyAnimation(m_textEditor2, "maximumWidth");
animation1->setStartValue(0);
animation1->setEndValue(100);
animation1->start();
```

EDIT: For minimumWidth property the animation works, but for maximumWidth - no. Thus I have opened a bug on their bugreport site: [here](http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12332).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just that maximumWidth isn't a very good property to use for animation, since it doesn't directly translate to the Widget's actual size.  You better use `geometry` which gives a better effect; like this for example, it animates a `QTextEdit`:

```
class QtTest : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        QtTest()
        {
            m_textEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
        };

    protected:
        QTextEdit *m_textEdit;

        virtual void showEvent ( QShowEvent * event )
        {
            QWidget::showEvent(event);

            QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(m_textEdit, "geometry");
            animation->setDuration(10000);
            animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
            animation->setEndValue(QRect(0, 0, 500, 30));

            animation->start();
        }
};
```

Comment: The promblem comes from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283587/qwidget-resize-animation question.So if it is not possible with maximumWidth, then how it is possible to solve the problem previous problem?

Comment: Honestly, I've been trying to help you with that, but that other code is just tooooo long. :-)  Laziness is a powerful force, young padawan!  I'm gonna take a wild guess here and say that resizing animations might not be working because of the Q*Layout guys.  Try this: put a Panel/ScrollBox/QWidget in the layout and the widget you want to animate inside it without *any* layouts.  Maybe that works.

Comment: Without layout to animate maximumWidth has no sence for my case. By the way minimumWidth property animates fine! So this should work as well, isn't it?