# Qt - There is a bug in QPropertyAnimation?

Tags: c++, qt

I face a very serious situation. By writing this question I hope that really professionals will express their opinion regarding to the problem I am going to describe. I have reported a bug in https://bugreports.qt.io/ :

> I have created QPropertyAnimation for maximumWidth property of QTextEdit and it does not work (it immediately changes state from starting state to the end state), though it works for minimumWidth property.
>       Please see the attached code.

And have attached .h and .cpp files. See those files [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12332) (files are named new.h and new.cpp).

And I got the follwing response:

> MaximumWidth is not the property you want to animate. It holds the maximum width that the widget can have, it's related to layouting and so on. Changing the maximumWidth (as well as the minimumWidth) does not necessarily trigger a relayout and repaint. You should animate the size.

Please explain me whether it is a bug or no? Please tell me how the minimumWith property is being animated but when it concerns to the maximumWidth property, then I should not work and that is OK? I just don't get their point... Please explain.

P.S. I have written this code because I wanted to close by animation the right QTextEdit and be sure that when I resize the main window, where the button and two QTextEdit are, the closed QTextEdit does not being restored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the actual value of maximumWidth? You don't seem to set a specific maximumWidth in your code.

The default value for maximumWidth is 16777215, and you set a duration of 1 msec. for the closing animation. Fading from 16777215 to 3 in 1 msec. would look like "instant", I guess.

Comment: When a set duration to the animation then it waits and only then does the same and immediately as it was.

Comment: Look, if you shrink from 16777215 to 3, if your screen has a width of 1000 pixels, you will only be able to see at most "1000 to 3" part, which is less than 0.006%… Try to modify the value of maximumWidth to a reasonable value before animating.

Comment: It is logical what you say, but what about the second animation, when I change from, say, 3 to 300. Once again I state that when I press the button and setDuration of anumation 3 seconds (for examle), then it waits 3 seconds and does it instantly. You could try yourself and make sure that it is true.

Comment: Hey it is not only logical, I have tested once agina and you'r right. Seems you know how works Qt better then Qt guys. At lease in the aspect this it true! Thanks a lot. This was a serious problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a bug; I'd call it "undefined behavior".  That means that if you try to animate minimumWidth, nobody can tell you for sure what is supposed to happen, and maybe the code has some optimizations or corner cases where sometimes it works, others it doesn't.

Anyway, minimumWidth and maximumWidth aren't supposed to be used to define what the size of a QWidget is, only what it must not exceed; i.e. they weren't designed to do what you are trying to do, so it can be called a bug.  If you want to animate, you have to use a deterministic approach, which in this case is using the geometry property.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, the response you got from the bug report pretty well explains the problem with your code and a solution.

Comment: The problem is when you animate with geometry (what I have done from the beginning), then when resize the window where the two QTextEdits and QPushButton are, the right-side QTextEdit is becoming opened :(. This was the problem that I wanted to control the maximumWidth in order to eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Sofahamster I have changed my code to the code below and it works fine. Thanks for your hint!

**Header file**

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT

    QTextEdit       *m_textEditor1;
    QTextEdit       *m_textEditor2;
    QPushButton     *m_pushButton;
    QHBoxLayout     *m_layout;
    QVBoxLayout     *m_buttonLayout;

    int              m_deltaX;
    bool             m_isClosed;


public:

    MyWidget(QWidget * parent = 0);
    ~MyWidget(){}

    void resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * event );

private slots:
    void closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool isClosing);

};
```

**Source file**

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget * parent):QWidget(parent),m_deltaX(0)
{

  m_pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
  m_pushButton->setText(">");
  m_pushButton->setCheckable(true);
  m_pushButton->setFixedSize(16,16);
  connect(m_pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool)));

  m_textEditor1 = new QTextEdit(this);
  m_textEditor1->setText("AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA  AA");

  m_textEditor2 = new QTextEdit(this);

  m_buttonLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
  m_buttonLayout->addWidget(m_pushButton);
  m_buttonLayout->addItem( new QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding) );


  m_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  m_layout->addWidget(m_textEditor1, 10);
  m_layout->addSpacing(15);
  m_layout->addLayout(m_buttonLayout);
  m_layout->setSpacing(0);
  m_layout->addWidget(m_textEditor2, 4);

  setLayout(m_layout);
  resize(800,500);
}

void MyWidget::closeOrOpenTextEdit2(bool isClosing)
{
    m_isClosed = isClosing;
    QPropertyAnimation *animation1 = new QPropertyAnimation(m_textEditor2, "maximumWidth");

    if(isClosing) //close the second textEdit
    {
        m_textEditor2->setMaximumWidth(m_textEditor2->width());

        int textEdit2_start = m_textEditor2->maximumWidth();

        m_deltaX = textEdit2_start;
        int textEdit2_end = 3;



        animation1->setDuration(500);
        animation1->setStartValue(textEdit2_start);
        animation1->setEndValue(textEdit2_end);


        m_pushButton->setText("<");

    }
    else //open
    {


        int textEdit2_start = m_textEditor2->maximumWidth();
        int textEdit2_end = m_deltaX;


        animation1->setDuration(500);
        animation1->setStartValue(textEdit2_start);
        animation1->setEndValue(textEdit2_end);


        m_pushButton->setText(">");

    }

    animation1->start();

}


void MyWidget::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * event )
{
    if(!m_isClosed)
        m_textEditor2->setMaximumWidth( QWIDGETSIZE_MAX );
}
```